# Error "Token request failed" when connecting to SharePoint site via PnP.Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp

New console application on .NET Framework 4.8 with latest PnP.Framework pack.

Code as follows:

```
string siteUrl = "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/DigitalInitiativePublicRelations";
string clientId = "ID";
string clientSecret = "SECRET";

using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
{
    cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
};
```

When running this code I get Token request failed error. I have registered the app in SharePoint (`/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx`) and given it Full Control permissions

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just built a new console application on .NET Framework 4.8 with latest PnP.Framework pack on a Windows 10 machine and it worked fine.

What version of Windows are you using? Your issues could be related to TLS ciphers. Please see [no longer able to use OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager OR PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/issues/336) for more information.

I'd also like to mention that the SharePoint team has been hinting that the Add-in model will be deprecated at some point in the not too distant future. This would mean that Azure ACS authentication will be deprecated as well. I would strongly suggest that you look at using Azure Active Directory to register your apps and authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to look at the exception message, because in my case I had a solution that had two projects and after installing the pnp framework the solution was with newtonsoft.json v12 and in the other project it was with newtonsoft.json v10, I discovered this by the message from exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of the important dependencies. The assembly manifest definition does not match the reference to the assembly. ( Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"

After discovering this I updated them both to have v12 and it worked.